# getting send grid credentials from web config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, sendgrid

How I can get Send Grid credentials from web config

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp.sendgrid.net" userName="username" password="password"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

instead of hardcoding them like this:

```
 // Init SmtpClient and send
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to store them in the `<appSettings>` section of your config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="sendGridUser" value="username" />
    <add key="sendGridPassword" value="password" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then use the `ConfigurationManager` class:

```
using System.Configuration; // May need to reference the assembly as well...don't remember

// ...

var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sendGridUser"];
var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sendGridPassword"];
```

Note: it isn't a bad idea to store the password string in a `SecureString` rather a normal `string` so that it doesn't hang around in memory after you're done with it. Further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx